# Select/export point features where the value change in two fields within the layer is less than a 5% change

Tags: qgis, point, select

I have a point layer that has two fields representing the distance (in feet) of a point feature to coastline (old distance vs. new distance). I want to crosscheck both fields to see the accuracy of my new distance calculations compared to the previous. Is there a way to select/export all point features have distance value calculations with a less than 5% change in value from the old distance calculation field compared to the new distance calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
("old distance" * 0.95) <= "new distance" AND "new distance" <= ("old distance" * 1.05)
```

Enter this into the `select by attribute` dialogue and save all selected features to a new shapefile.

Comment: Erik, Appreciate the impromptu help! It worked like a charm.